# How can I display an image from my database to a view page in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want profile pictures from users to be displayed on the profile pages of the users. (I'm still a beginner with codeigniter)

The db row where the pictures are stored: profiel_foto
The folder where the pictures are in: upload

I tried to do it like this: `Profile picture:  <?php echo $_SESSION['profiel_foto']; ?><br>`

But that doesn't work with pictures.

I am able to load pictures like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/1498736939jeremy.jpg">
```

But thats not how I want to load it. I want to load profile pictures by using the profiel_foto column

Comment: what does it store: $_SESSION['profiel_foto'] ? Can you print the value and let us know?

Comment: Yes I'm getting this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: profiel_foto

Filename: views/profile.php

Line Number: 18

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/profile.php
Line: 18
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/User.php
Line: 21
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Make sure that session contains the image name  <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/ <?php echo $_SESSION['profiel_foto']; ?>">

Comment: If i copy that code is says the same error

Comment: print_r($_SESSION); EXIT;  to know that session setting properly or not

Comment: Still getting this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: profiel_foto

Filename: views/profile.php

Line Number: 19

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/profile.php
Line: 19
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/User.php
Line: 22
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: did you setting session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `$_SESSION['profiel_foto']` contains the user image name

And `Embed` the `file name` in `img` tag like this

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $_SESSION['profiel_foto']; ?>">
```

**Note :**

**1st** : your error seems your not setting session index like `profiel_foto`

**2nd** : Make sure that session library loaded

You do this from within `config/autoload.php.`

```
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Or you can load the session library on each page like this

`$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: Hello, I used this code: <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $_SESSION['profiel_foto']; ?>"> and I loaded the session library but I'm still getting this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: profiel_foto

Filename: views/profile.php

Line Number: 19

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/profile.php
Line: 19
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/User.php
Line: 22
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: first of all did you setting session or not ?

Comment: I did this in autoload file: $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

Comment: It's loading the library . but you need to set the session value when user login

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the profile pic from table and show it on profile. You can do something like below (as i am not sure what and where you are missing the logic)
In controller you can write like below:

```
$data['profilePic'] = $this->db->query("Your query to user table")->row()->profiel_foto;
$this->load->view('view file', $data);
```

And in View

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $profilePic?>">
```

I am assuming you are storing image name in table with column 'profiel_foto'.

Comment: What do I need to fill in : ("Your query to user table")

Comment: you need to write a query to fetch data from the table.